# Radio button automatic change the data in php

Tags: javascript, php

I am new to php i am keeping 2 radio buttons one is checked default when page is loaded the content should be displayed for the radiobutton based content default

Comment: please share some code

Comment: no need of php there.. You can use it with javascript

Comment: can u please share any snipset code for that

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help to understand,

```
   <?php
   $sex='male';
   ?>
  <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male"  <?php if($sex=='male') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>>Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" <?php if($sex=='female') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>>Female
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Some Tips and ideas to do that:

You load 2 different divs, 1 for each radio button.

1 is the default,

The other 1 is hidden, until somebody select the other radio button.

When the radio button is selected, u execute some javascript code.

Use

```
getELementbyId(IDofDIV)
```

to switch

```
display:hidden
```

to

```
display:block
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**Use this:**

<fieldset>
    <legend>Gender:</legend>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="bloke" value="M">
    <label for="bloke">Male</label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="sheila" value="F">
    <label for="sheila">Female</label>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below sample code for your better understanding:

```
<?php $value='male';?>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"  <?php if($value=='male') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>>Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" <?php if($value=='female') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>>Female
```

Comment: i got that one but when page loades the default content of the radio button should display but it was showing plain page when i click on that radio button it was showing